# Error While creating Date Picker in Android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-date

i got this error while creating date picker in android  `"Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead"`

```
 public class Insert extends Activity {

    private Header header;
    private EditText etName;
    private EditText etAge;
    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private static final int ID_DATEPICKER = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.insert);

        header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.layoutHeader);
        header.init();

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_age);


        Button datePickerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
        datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(datePickerButtonOnClickListener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener datePickerButtonOnClickListener= new Button.OnClickListener()
    {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    myYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    myMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    myDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDialog(ID_DATEPICKER);
   }
  };

 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(id)
  {
    case ID_DATEPICKER:
    Toast.makeText(Insert.this,"- onCreateDialog -",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    int myYear;
    int myMonth;
    int myDay;
    return new DatePickerDialog(this,myDateSetListener,myYear, myMonth, myDay);

   default:
    return null;
  }
 }

 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
 {
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String date = "Year: " + String.valueOf(year) + "\n"+ "Month: " + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1) + "\n"+ "Day: " + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
    Toast.makeText(Insert.this, date, 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } 
 };


 findViewById(R.id.btnInsert).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

                DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(Insert.this);
                dbAdapter.openDataBase();

                ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                initialValues.put("name", etName.getText().toString());
                initialValues.put("age", etAge.getText().toString());               
                long n = dbAdapter.insertRecordsInDB("user", null, initialValues);              
                Toast.makeText(Insert.this, "new row inserted with id = "+n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

}
```

This is code where error is occurring.
can any one suggest me how to remove this error??

Comment: where are you creating Date picker

Comment: where is the code for Date Picker and how can u tell the error is causing becoz of above code?

Comment: And error is occurring  at findViewById(R.id.btnInsert).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
 Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInser);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

////your code goes here
    }
    });
```